# How to calculate x*x.T in python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to calculate the following:

[image: x * x.T]

but I have no idea how to do this in python, I do not want to implement this manually but use a predefined function for this, something from numpy for example.

But `numpy` seems to ignore that x.T should be transposed.

Code:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 5])

print(np.dot(x, x.T))  # = 26, This is not the matrix it should be!
```

Comment: That's the inner, dot, product (as the name implies)!  Did you read the `np.dot` docs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your vectors are defined as 1-d arrays, you can use `np.outer`:

```
np.outer(x, x.T)
> array([[ 1,  5],
>       [ 5, 25]])
```

Alternatively, you could also define your vectors as matrices and use normal matrix multiplication:

```
x = np.array([[1], [5]])
x @ x.T
> array([[ 1,  5],
>       [ 5, 25]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
x = np.array([[1], [5]])

print(np.dot(x, x.T))
```

Your original `x` is of shape (2,), while you need a shape of (2,1). Another way is reshaping your `x`:

```
x = np.array([1, 5]).reshape(-1,1)

print(np.dot(x, x.T))
```

`.reshape(-1,1)` reshapes your array to have 1 column and implicitely takes care of number of rows.

output:

```
[[ 1  5]
 [ 5 25]]
```

Comment: I should have added, that I want to do this for x of arbitrary dimension, how can I reshape the array this way? `np.reshape(x, len(x)) just gives me x back.

Comment: @OnkelZukunft Added reshaping. Please find the edit. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
np.matmul(x[:, np.newaxis], [x])
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.